# If $\text{lcm}(a,b,c,d)=a+b+c+d$, then $\gcd(abcd,15)>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

$\text{LCM}(a,b,c,d)=a+b+c+d$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Prove that $abcd$ is divisible by at least one of $3$ and $5$.

I am not sure how to create this proof. Does it involve divisibility tests? How should I set it out?

Comment: For what it's worth, $abcd=\gcd(a\gcd(b\gcd(c;d);cd);bcd)(a+b+c+d)$.

Comment: I've just found an example, it's 1,2,6,9.

Comment: That is because $\text{LCM}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\text{LCM}(a_1,\text{LCM}(a_2,\ldots,a_n)), \forall a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $\text{LCM}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Comment: And another: 1,4,5,10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We suppose that $a\ge b\ge c\ge d\ge 1$ and $s=a+b+c+d$ is the lowest common multiple of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Now, by contradiction, we suppose that $s$ is not a multiple of $3$ nor $5$.

Note that if $a=b=c=d$ then $4a=s$ (because $s$ is the sum) and $s=a$ (because $s$ is the lcm). This is not possible.

1. As $a<s<4a$ and $s$ is a multiple of $a$, then $s=2a$ (can't be $3a$) and $b+c+d=a$, so $b<a$
2. $a=b+c+d\le 3b$. Hence $2b<s=2a\le 6b$. So $s=4b$ (can't be $3b$, $5b$ or $6b$). $a=2b$ and $c+d=b$, so $c<b$
3. $b=c+d\le 2c$. Hence $4c<s=4b\le 8c$. So either $s=7c$ or $s=8c$ (can't be $5c$ or $6c$).

Now two possibilities :

1. $s=8c=4b=2a$ Hence $d=c$, and $s=lcm(a,b,c,d)=a$. A contradiction
2. $s=7c=4b=2a$ Hence, there is a $k$ such that $a=14k$, $b=7k$, $c=4k$ and $d=3k$ (because $s=a+b+c+d=2a=28k$), so $d$ is a multiple of $3$, contradiction.

Hence, $s$ is a multiple of $3$ or $5$ and as $s$ divides $abcd$, so is $abcd$.

Note that it is obviously always a multiple of $2$ also, because if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are all odd, then $s=a+b+c+d$ would be even, a contradiction.

Some examples :

- only multiple of $3$ : 4,  3,  3,  2
- only multiple of $5$ : 5,  2,  2,  1
- multiple of $15$ : 15, 10,  3,  2

---

After that, you can prove with a similar method that there only 9 different (with $a\ge b\ge c\ge d$) solutions with $gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$, and that all other solutions are multiples of one of this nine primitive solution.

$$
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
a&b&c&d&s\\\hline
 4&  3&  3&  2 &   12\\
  4&  4&  3&  1 &   12\\
  5&  2&  2&  1 &   10\\
  6&  4&  1&  1 &   12\\
  9&  6&  2&  1 &   18\\
 10&  5&  4&  1 &   20\\
 12&  8&  3&  1 &   24\\
 15& 10&  3&  2 &   30\\
 21& 14&  6&  1 &   42\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: +1. Marvelous solution. The fact that $s$ being a multiple of $3$ or $5$ implies $abcd$ being a multiple of $3$ or $5$ can be derived from the formula $abcd=\gcd(a\gcd(b\gcd(c;d);cd);bcd)(a+b+c+d)$ but of course the formula is not needed as it is intuitively obvious that $\text{lcm}(a,b,c,d)\mid abcd$.

Comment: @user314 In fact a common multiple of $x$ and $y$ is always a multiple of their lcm.

Comment: @barto true. ${}$

Comment: Is there a primitive form with both a multiple of 3 and 5 neigther multiples of 5 and 3 resp.